# Creating P2 Repository via tycho does not add dependency into resulting repository

Tags: maven, tycho

I have a separate project which contains:

```xml
<packaging>eclipse-repository</packaging>
```

a larger number of dependencies and the following part in my pom file:

```xml
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <environments>
                    <environment>
                        <os>win32</os>
                        <ws>win32</ws>
                        <arch>x86</arch>
                    </environment>
                </environments>
                <pomDependencies>consider</pomDependencies>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-p2-repository-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <includeAllDependencies>true</includeAllDependencies>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
```

I'm using tycho 0.24.0. So I can build this project and results in a zip file a p2artifacts.xml and p2content.xml which contain the dependencies. So far so good.

But now I add two other dependencies:

```xml
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mvel</groupId>
      <artifactId>mvel2</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have checked if those two artifacts contain OSGi information in their MANIFEST.MF. Furthermore they will be downloaded during the build of the project which means maven coordinates are correct etc.

But in the end they will not being packaged into the zip nor they occur in the p2artifacts.xml neither in the p2content.xml.

Does someone has an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I simply forgot to add the dependencies to the `category.xml` file.

Answer (score 1):

I simply forgot to add the dependencies to the `category.xml`.